# Using babel, cannot set breakpoints in ES6 generators

Tags: ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, generator, babeljs, source-maps

In a typical react app, using babel with the presets `es2015`, `react` and `stage-2` and with sourcemaps enabled, setting the breakpoint in a generator function, the breakpoint will move automatically to somewhere else.

.**babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
}
```

Comment: Which debugger are you using?

Comment: Chrome debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug with either the source maps of the transform or the source map support in the Chrome Devtools. this is a result of using babel, disabling `generator-transpilation` solves this.

Here's what I used,

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"],
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```